# WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder when hosting without IIS on Windows

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm planning to host Asp.Net Core 2 application without IIS on Windows.

The default way to create web host seems to be using `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`. But what is confusing me is that inside there is a call to the method `UseIISIntegration`.

Is it ok to use `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` when hosting Asp.Net Core 2 app without IIS on Windows? Or other options are advisable?

Comment: Yes, you can use WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder when deploying your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its absolutely fine to use `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`

As when hosting with IIS it just work as proxy and redirect request to kestrel server.

It doesn't create much of problem.

Take a look at this article [here](https://blog.dudak.me/2017/what-does-webhost-createdefaultbuilder-do/)